# Google People API Connection List Issue c#, asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, google-people-api

I am using Google People API to fetch all contacts. Here is the code that I am using.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UserProfile([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();            
    var service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = cred
    });            
    try
    {

        var request = service.People.Connections.List("people/me");
        request.PersonFields = "names";                
        var person = await request.ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return View();
}
```

Getting 403 Error.

Note: already added scope

Error Details:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.people.v1.PeopleService.ListConnections",
          "service": "people.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Which scope are you using? This `people.connections.list` method requires one of these `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly`. Maybe the access token doesn't have the correct scopes. Try going through the authorization flow again to get a new access token with the correct scopes authorized and see if that works.

Comment: Hey Lorena
I am using both of these scopes mentioned by you.
Can you please let me know how to get a new access token.
I am completely new.
Initially I didn't added any scope and again I have added this scopes after login from console.

Comment: There should be a token.json file somewhere in your directory, delete that file and run your code again to go through the authorization flow again.

Comment: Hey Lorena there is no any token.json file exist in my directory, can you please help me to get rid of this.
Thanks

Comment: Look for your app name from this list myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1 and remove it, make sure you have the scopes mentioned above in your authorization code and run the code again, it should bring the consent screen to verify consent again. Let me know if that works.